# Social Search Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, social-networking

The question is oriented towards a research that I have been conducting since 3 months. What are the social search engines available currently (if any)? What is the future of semantic + social(collective) intelligence collection/distribution engines?

Comment: The future is Skynet. We're all gonna die.

Comment: Check out Ellerdale - they did some cool stuff with correlating current social media buzz with defined topics scraped from wikipedia and other sources, so you could see a topic that was hot at a certain time, not just a phrase. They've since been acquired by Flipboard.

Comment: @user427393 : Google would have done that if google wave had succeeded but without intelligence :-)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some terms of art here, but I can't decode this. May I suggest either explaining your terms in a little more detail or linking to explanations from them. In particular what do you mean by "social search"?

Comment: @dmckee I used a confusing term here. I am sorry for this. I meant that if there are any startups which are using social data or social graph of a person to in orders to provide results to user specified search queries. Is there any future for these type of algorithms? If I am still unclear please let me know.

Comment: @mjb: If you want a chance of having this re-opened you would edit the question with your clarification (and perhaps a request for re-opening). That will bump it back to the top of the active queue, so people will see it again. I suspect that it will be judged as borderline at best. However, you might have better luck over at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)...I don't follow that site closely so I'm not sure, but the "does this approach have a future" angle might fly.